# How to link SAP tables (EKPO, MARA, ...) with SAP transactions (ME23n, ME3M, ...)?

Tags: sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

I want to automate SAP Exports in my Company and query Data from transactions directly from our Datalake. The only problem is that the query results differ from the exported Data directly from SAP ERP. It seems like the wrong attributes/tables are used. Is there a simple way to find a link between SAP ERP transactions and the underlying SAP ERP data tables? Like to reproduce transaction `ME3M` you need following attributes from tables `ekpo`, `mara` and so on.

I've read about transaction `ST05` (SQL trace) but sadly this transaction is restricted (I work in a really big company were approval processes are very slow). Is there an alternate way to find out which SAP ERP tables are referenced when calling a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. Every SAP transaction contains complex logic which involved hundreds of data tables, so it is not one-to-one relation but many-to-many. This logic was never documented in any help file.

Partly it can be decoded via debugging or via SQL trace you mentioned. SQL trace is the only reliable way to understand which SAP tables were pulled in concrete transaction.